# Symfony2 ManyTo One relation form

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-forms

I have two entities City OneToMany Anagrafic,
I make the form with the field AnagraficType city (use a hidden attribute because the handpiece using javascript) in this way:

```
class Anagrafic
{
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="City", inversedBy="anagrafics", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="city_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $city;
//..
//..
class City
{
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Anagrafic", mappedBy="city", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $anagrafics;
//...
//...
class AnagraficType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('comune', 'hidden')
```

when I save the form back to me this error:

```
Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object,
string given in /var/www/MyBusiness0_1/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php line 1559
```

I don't understand what's wrong!

Comment: That would be *Anagraphic*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15043485/2036211

Here solve this problem, you should use the DataTransformer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, your `AnagraficType` form will let you choose one city. If yes, you should use [entity Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/entity.html) rendering a `<select>` element.

Btw, your mapppings are wrong: `cascade` should be defined on the **inverse side of a bidirectional relation**, that is `City` (the **owning side `Anagraphic`** holds the `inversedBy` attribute).

Comment: I use a hidden field because you edit in select with javascript (Select2)
I tried to remove cascade={"persist"} from Anagrafic but always the same error. `/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="City", inversedBy="anagrafics")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="city_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $city;`