# Symfony2 Expected argument of type "object or array", "string" given

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I'm trying desperately to save the form with entity City OneToMany Anagrafic.
I entered the "property_path" CityType the form and I returned error,

```
Expected argument of type “object or array”, “string” given
```

I do not understand what I'm doing wrong!

```
class Anagrafic
{
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="City", inversedBy="anagrafics", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="city_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
private $city;
//..
//..
class City
{
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Anagrafic", mappedBy="city", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $anagrafics;
//...
//...
class CityType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('comune', 'hidden', array('property_path' => 'city.id'))
//..
//..
class AnagraficType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('city', new CityType())
```

EDIT: Sorry for the incomplete information, this is the exception:

```
CRITICAL - Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException: 
Expected argument of type "object or array", "string" given (uncaught exception) at
 /var/www/MyBusiness0_1/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Util/PropertyPath.php line 342 


/var/www/MyBusiness0_1/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Util/PropertyPath.php at line 342   
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $lastIndex; ++$i) {
        if (!is_object($objectOrArray) && !is_array($objectOrArray)) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($objectOrArray, 'object or array');
        }
        $property = $this->elements[$i];
```

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: it is a quiz! "I got an error, and will not show the complete code or point of error"

Comment: It is in title. `Expected argument of type “object or array”, “string” given`

Comment: ... on line ... in file ...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "... on line ... in file ..."

Comment: Normally when you get a exception, parse error, syntax error etc. there will be the file and linenumber listed on which the error occured. If you post the corresponding code maybe we could help you.

Comment: Sorry, I update the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem was that when you pass a string or a number, symfony expects an object, so we need to implement a DataTransformer to turn a string into object and vice versa.

http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html

Problem solved! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `propertyPath` expects a object or a array. So this line is wrong:

```
$builder->add('comune', 'hidden', array('property_path' => 'city.id'))
```

You are passing `city.id` here and that shouldn't be a string. I'm not a Symfony user and not familiar with the FormBuilder so you have to lookup the manual how to use the `property_path` option.

Btw. this has nothing to do with doctrine 2, so it would be appropiate to delete that tag.

Comment: the fact is that if you do not use the "property_path", I receive this error: `An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO City (city, zip, region_id, state_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params {"1":"8094","2":null,"3":null,"4":null}:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'zip' cannot be null` Try to save a new entity City, but City is a list of cities already predefined and the relationship City OneToMany Anagrafic should not have to create a new entity!
What is wrong?